# How to manage daytime saving(summer time) on oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Let say I have recorded production time for 2020-05-01 17:00:00 on production_time column on TABLE A and when I query

```
select production_time from A
```

after summer time ends, it should display 2020-05-01 16:00:00 on the app. Is there a way to do this without changing query every time summer time starts and end? I need to put just one select query on app and that changes time difference automatically when summer time starts or end without changing query or modify saved value on column. Yelp. :D

Comment: Why would I display a different conversion? In Oracle the conversion stays the same, before and after the date. Unless, there was a DST error that was corrected at some point via a software update.

Comment: That's a strange requirement, from my point of view. Why would you want to do that? In Zagreb, we have "Grički top" (cannon that fires every day at noon). And then, several months later, you'd say that it fired at 11 AM. Well, it did not. It fired at noon. Why misinterpreting reality?

Comment: No it should not change.  That is what the time value was then.  Are you saying you want to store a date in standard time

Comment: The logic of your app doesn't make too much sense to me. Why do you want to display a different / wrong point in time?

Comment: Agree with all comments.  You don't change time in history just because of a current DST change.

Comment: I suppose original developers did this to server on purpose in order to prevent to have duplicated date record time when summer time ends. They turned off auto time adjust during daytime option on database server and now we have millions of data that recorded correctly when daysaving was not active but -1 hours for every data that was recorded during daysaving time. I don't even know how I am going to fix this. :(